# db schema comparison

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

i am trying to compare two databases on my SQL Server 2008 using the VSTS Db edition schema compare. I am getting an error "schema comparison not supported for sql 2008".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link suggesting the fix
http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/10/29/visual-studio-2008-and-sql-server-2008-schema-compare-fixed-requires-this-gdr.aspx

This seems to be a known design limitation of VSTS 2008 DB edition, which was fixed in the GDR RC1 release/patch as you may call it.